# How to count common values in dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I count how many common values two dictionaries have?

It's a little more complicated than that actually:

```
d1 = {'1':['4','2','3'], '2':['4','3',], '3':['4','6','7']}
d2 = {'1': ['val1','val2'], '2': ['val1', 'val3', 'val4'], '4': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], '6': ['val2']}
d3 = {}
```

I want to find out how many 'vals', let's say, '1' and '2', have in common. So then I look at the second dictionary and since 1 and 2 both contain 'val1', I create a new dictionary `d3 = {'val1' : 1}`

---

- copied from comment

let me clarify, the numbers can be a part of both dictionaries, but the vals are only in the second one. My function takes only one argument essentially, aside from those two dictionaries, and so let's say our parameter was '1'. It is supposed to look at the first dictionary, look at that list, and find those values (as keys) in the second dictionary, and then find what '1' and its values from d1 have in common in d2. so '1' and 4 have 'val1' and 'val2' in common, '1' and '2' have 'val1' in common, '1' and '3' have nothing in common

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I don't understand the fonction of d1

Comment: Not clear. Do you want to get common keys of `d1` and `d2`, i.e. `1` and `2`, or the "intersection" of the values of those keys from `d2`, i.e. `['val1']`, and where does the `1` in your `d3` come from?

Comment: sorry, let me clarify, the numbers can be a part of both dictionaries, but the vals are only in the second one. My function takes only one argument essentially, aside from those two dictionaries, and so let's say our parameter was '1'. It is supposed to look at the first dictionary, look at that list, and find those values (as keys) in the second dictionary, and then find what '1' and its values from d1 have in common in d2. so '1' and 4 have 'val1' and 'val2' in common, '1' and '2' have 'val1' in common, '1' and '3' have nothing in common...

Comment: It seems from your question and your comment that you have identified your requirements and gone a bit further by thinking about how to go about this. What specifically are you having trouble with? - iterating over dictionary items? - comparing values?  If you include, in your question, any of your solutions and point out why they are deficient it will be easier to get you back on track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
d1 = {'1':['4','2','3'], '2':['4','3',], '3':['4','6','7']}
d2 = {'1': ['val1','val2'], '2': ['val1', 'val3', 'val4'], '4': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'], '6': ['val2']}
d3 = {}

def find_common_element(foo):
    result = {}
    if foo in d1 :
        for elem in d1[foo]:
            if str(elem) in d2 :
                common = set(d2['1']) & set(d2[str(elem)])
                result[str(elem)] = common
    return result


print("check 1")
print(find_common_element('1'))
print("check 2")
print(find_common_element('2'))
print("check 3")
print(find_common_element('3'))
```

Output :

```
check 1
{'4': {'val2', 'val1'}, '2': {'val1'}}
check 2
{'4': {'val2', 'val1'}}
check 3
{'4': {'val2', 'val1'}, '6': {'val2'}}
```